# how to retrieve data from database monthly based on date if data not available it should display null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data like this format...

```
ID  id  date                     time           total
-----------------------------------------------------------    
51  192 2012-08-14 00:00:00.000 02:10 PM    4900.00
51  191 2012-08-11 00:00:00.000 03:20 PM    5500.00
51  35  2012-08-17 00:00:00.000 10:30 AM    2900.00
51  35  2012-08-17 00:00:00.000 11:50 AM    10800.00
51  192 2012-10-23 00:00:00.000 04:00 PM    2900.00
51  192 2012-10-23 00:00:00.000 03:00 PM    2900.00
51  192 2012-10-23 00:00:00.000 10:10 AM    2900.00
51  192 2012-10-23 00:00:00.000 02:50 PM    2300.00
51  191 2012-11-16 00:00:00.000 04:00 PM    2900.00
```

I would like to display `sum(total)` on a monthly basis. If bookings are not available entire month that month should display 0 value. Because I would like to plot that month value to chart.

Could you please help on this query?

Comment: Did you forget to paste the query you were trying with?

Comment: How do you work out if bookings are 'not available entire month' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
select  Years,number as Month,isnull(Total,0) as Total
from(
    select number 
    from master..spt_values 
    where type='P' 
    and number between 1 and 12) seq
cross join (select distinct Year([date]) as Years from Table1) y
left join
    (select Year([date])as Year,month([date])as Month,sum(total) as Total
     from Table1 
     group by  Year([date]),month([date]))t
on seq.number=t.Month
and t.year=y.Years
```

## [SQL fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/598af/12)

Comment: If bookings are not available entire month that month it skips that month. i want to display 0 value which is skipped month too

Comment: If you have multiple year, then you should group by year.. also

Comment: no year that number(month) which you gave takes only one time. actually that should repeat yearly

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19871/discussion-between-user1740091-and-joe-g-joseph)

Answer (score 0):

this one works in oracle

```
  select  <place your rest  of required columns> 
    ,to_char(date,'month') Month,sum(total) total 
     from talbe1 group by to_char(date,'month')
      ,<place your rest  of required columns> ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Query :

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d27b1/15)**

```
SELECT 
t.month
,isnull(SUM(total),0) AS total
FROM (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12)
      )  AS t(month)
LEFT JOIN Table1 t1
  ON MONTH(t1.date) = t.month
GROUP BY t.month
```

Result:

```
| MONTH | TOTAL |
-----------------
|     1 |     0 |
|     2 |     0 |
|     3 |     0 |
|     4 |     0 |
|     5 |     0 |
|     6 |     0 |
|     7 |     0 |
|     8 | 24100 |
|     9 |     0 |
|    10 | 11000 |
|    11 |  2900 |
|    12 |     0 |
```